# Get values from the table using MySQL joins

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

In mysql I have 3 tables called as

```
ps_product_lang

ps_order_detail

and ps_image
```

here are the tables sample data

```
=== ps_product_lang ===


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_product_lang` (
  `id_product` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_shop` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `id_lang` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `description_short` text,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_product`,`id_shop`,`id_lang`),
  KEY `id_lang` (`id_lang`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `ps_product_lang`
--

INSERT INTO `ps_product_lang` (`id_product`, `id_shop`, `id_lang`, `description`, `description_short`,  `name`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, '<p>this is dummy</p>', '<p>dummy</p>', 'dummy product')
);


===== ps_order_detail===
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_order_detail` (
      `id_order_detail` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `id_order` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_order_detail`),
      KEY `product_id` (`product_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `ps_order_detail`
    --

    INSERT INTO `ps_order_detail` (`id_order_detail`, `id_order`,  `product_id`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 2);

========= ps_image =========
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ps_image` (
  `id_image` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_product` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `position` smallint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cover` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_image`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_product_image` (`id_image`,`id_product`,`cover`),
  KEY `image_product` (`id_product`),
  KEY `id_product_cover` (`id_product`,`cover`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=24 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `ps_image`
--

INSERT INTO `ps_image` (`id_image`, `id_product`, `position`, `cover`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1),
(2, 1, 2, 0),
(3, 1, 3, 0),
(4, 1, 4, 0),
(5, 2, 1, 0),
(6, 2, 2, 0),
(7, 2, 3, 1),
(8, 3, 1, 1),
(9, 3, 2, 0),
(10, 4, 1, 1),
(11, 4, 2, 0),
(12, 5, 1, 1),
(13, 5, 2, 0),
(14, 5, 3, 0),
(15, 5, 4, 0),
(16, 6, 1, 1),
(17, 6, 2, 0),
(18, 6, 3, 0),
(19, 6, 4, 0),
(20, 7, 1, 1),
(21, 7, 2, 0),
(22, 7, 3, 0),
(23, 7, 4, 0);
```

So here I want to get all the field like

```
id_order_detail id_product name id_image(from ps_image table where cover = 1)
```

To get id_order_detail id_product name I am using this mysql inner join

```
SELECT DISTINCT (a.id_order_detail),(b.id_product),(b.name)
        FROM ps_order_detail a join 
        ps_product_lang b on a.product_id=b.id_product GROUP BY(name)
```

This one is giving me `id_order_detail id_product name`

Now I want to get `id_image from the ps_image table where the cover value is 1 for the product_id`

So can someone tell me how to do this one? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: `DISTINCT` is pointless if you have `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

can you not just join the third table on the product_id as well? like this

```
SELECT a.id_order_detail, b.id_product, b.name, c.id_image
FROM ps_order_detail a 
join ps_product_lang b on a.product_id=b.id_product 
join ps_image c on c.id_product = a.product_id
where c.cover = 1
```